# Learning Magento extension Development

Tags: magento-1.9, php, mysql, development, extensions

I am New in Magento i want to Develop magento Extension I know Php and MySql and web Development . I am finding easiest way to Learn Magento developing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get answer for this just by little search,
anyway here are some which I found.

1)[Link1](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643)

2)[Link2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/create_your_extension/)

3)[Link3](http://www.pierrefay.com/magento-developper-guide-howto-tutorial-5)

4)[Link4](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/)